# Laravel - Get specific array in JSON encoded database column

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have a table called `Posts` with these columns:

```
-- uid (int)
-- title (str)
-- body (text)
-- data (json)
```

and in one row, inside the `data` column, I have a JSON encoded response like so:

```
[{
    "title": "Blue",
    "points": 0,
    "tags": [{
        "type": "Comedy",
        "uid": 45
    }]
}, {
    "title": "Green Orange",
    "points": 2,
    "tags": [{
        "type": "Horror",
        "uid": 1
    }]
}]
```

All of that is `json_encode` into one database column.

How can I make it so that I can get the `Green Orange` into a variable?

I have tried:

```
$post = Post::where('id', $id)->first();

$data = json_decode($post->data);

return $data[0];
```

But that just gives me: `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"object\" given.`

Comment: what is the output of `dd($data)` ?

Comment: `json_decode`provides by default `\StdClass` use this to retrieve an array `json_decode($post->data, true);` And access properties with `$data[0]['title']`

Comment: although irrelevant to your question, I would recommend `$post = Post::find($id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the full object, instead you need its field:

```
$post = Post::where('id', $id)->first();//$post = Post::find($id); would be better

$data = json_decode($post->data);

return $data[1]->title;//note than Green Orange is in the second object of the array, so not index 0 but 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the title field in the second object of array.

```html
return $data[1]->title;
```